# Android VM: Can avd run on a host with Hyper-V?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-virtual-device, hyper-v

I have this issue trying to run a virtual android device on my computer which runs Hyper-V because I use docker containers. The host s.o. is Windows 10 Pro. Android Studio installed, and its updates.
When I try to run a virtual device a blue screen shows and system restarts.
I want to start learning Flutter but I'm stuck in this.
**Any solution / Work around?**

Answer (score 0):

From the [Android developer's blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html), you'll want to ensure your hardware and software are supported and versions are current.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, all steps and requirements checked and properly configured!
And I missed the Hypervisor Platform. So with this installed, the blue screen does not show up, but the virtual device doesn't boot.

Answer (score 0):

Blue screen errors can be happened because of a hardware or driver errors. Please take a picture of the error and send it to us. But a general solution is to open device manager (devmgmt.msc) then check if there is a yellow sign on a driver or not. Please check if all of the drivers has been installed properly. After that, You should check if Intel virtualization technology is turned on in BIOS system

Comment: Thank you for your help!! Thanks to @jesse-lawson answer the blue screen does not show, but the device does not boot up...

Comment: You can find the Error in event viewer under application logs. Share the log with us, see if we can solve your problem or not. Again Please check the driver status of your system in devmgmt.msc. Some systems need chipset drivers to do it.

Comment: I reinstall some drivers and I made the avd boot up, but only for a moment, and then it closes. This is the log in Android Studio:
03/05/2020
15:46 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

15:47 Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037

15:47 Emulator: F:\Android\sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Unexpected VP exit code 5

15:47 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Make a backup of .android file in user folder then delete it, Disable any firewall and av in your system then reboot it. I think your adb will work properly